# Installing OpenCv on Azure JupyterNoteBook

Tags: python, azure, opencv, jupyter-notebook, azure-notebooks

How can i get Open Cv library installed on my Azure Jupyter NoteBook.Having used the command that shows the version of Open Cv,it returns "no module found".Is there a way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Select console in the left menu. Here you can install modules using pip or conda.

Another way, you can install opencv from Jupyter Notebook using this code:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: It worked fine but my output code keeps crashing the kernel so i dont get to see the result